# PHP Get xml nodes by index

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

How to loop thru any XML file to get node and it's values?

My struggle is: I have 3 XML files:

```
<namespace>
  <node>
    <value_a>A</value_a>
    <value_b>B</value_b>
  </node>
</namespace>

<global>
  <country>
    <code>UK</code>
  </country>
</global>

<geoNames>
  <country>
    <countryCode>Australia</countryCode>
  </country>
</geoNames>
```

And I am reading them with 3 same looking functions that extract information from XML and store as variables by saving .php data file. Example of one of them:

```
$parsed_xml_content = "";

$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://" . $srvname . $dirpath . $file_xmlData); 

$obj = $xml->xpath("//geonames");

foreach ($obj[0]->country as $country)
{
    $keys = (array_keys((array) $country));

    $i = 0;
    $parsed_xml_content .= "\t\"" . $country->countryCode . "\" => Array(\n";
    foreach ($country as $val)
    {
        $parsed_xml_content .= "\t\t\"$keys[$i]\" => \"$val\",\n";

        $i++;
    }
    $parsed_xml_content .= "\t),\n";
}

$fo = fopen($locpath . $file_roots, "w");

fwrite($fo, "<?php \$isoGeoData = Array(\n" . $parsed_xml_content . "\n); ?>");

fclose($fo);
```

How to rewrite it to not use node names `$country->countryCode` but indexes? Managing 3 functions get's messy.

Comment: As I can understand you want to create a array with xml ?

Comment: you might be as well interested in the following php function: http://php.net/var_export

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a peace of code that I normally use for array to xml or xml to array.

[php-array-to-xml or xml-to-array](https://snipt.net/robertbanh/php-array-to-xml/)

you can use the same `class` or just copy this `toArray` function in your script.

after creating `array` you can use php `serialize()` [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function for writing the result with `fwrite()`